# Does radiation count as splash damage?

Tags: borderlands-3

I'm currently using a Moze splash damage build, and I just acquired the "Atom Balm Commander Planetiod" Legendary artifact, which increases the "Aura burst radius" of radiation damage.

Does this count as splash damage with regards to Moze's skills? Should I be using this artifact, or does "Aura burst" not proc any of Moze's skills that proc with dealt splash damage?

Additionally, I also have another relic that sports a "+33% Area-Of-Effect Damage" modifier- does this also effect elemental "Aura burst?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Radiation does count as splash damage according to the [Borderlands wikia](https://borderlands.fandom.com/wiki/Radiation):

> "Radiation has been added as a replacement/adaptation of the explosive element from previous installments, which now finds itself as splash damage, rather than its own element."

It's discussed further on [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/borderlands3/comments/d6uqpm/is_radiation_particularly_good_for_a_moze_splash/) where users discuss and accept using Radiation as a primary element for a Moze build. There's a [similar discussion](https://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/t/what-counts-as-splash-damage/3565483/6) on the Gearbox forums too.

In regards to your second question of Aura Boost: there is [another post on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands/comments/d9a5hu/radiation_status_effect_aura/) which makes the same inquiry.

Reddit user u/GreenDragon245 performs some tests:

> "It does not boost the red suit shield tested this with a lvl 31 red suit the 1 that says warning containment failure I believe just to make sure.
>
> Tested this with no rad boost just the shield 145dmg per pulse when near enemies equipped a similar relic with aura dmg+50% and aura burst dmg and burst radius both 12% still 145 per pulse. Even with a different relic that grant's a aura when u slam I had a rad one two different rad dmg values showed up 145 and 200 something so ya that's your answer.
>
> Oh 1 more my guardian ranks were locked when I tried this so iam sure it does not boost the red suit
>
> What the relic says is it boosts radiation when a enemies is infected with radiation it has a aura remember? Lol that dmg harms other things nearby now the relic makes since
>
> One final test I did was with moze nuclear warheads on her mech on a vehicle see if it boosted the dmg no it did not 918 and 63ish rad tick dmg with it on and off"

And concludes:

> "In conclusion it does not boost radiation dmg directly but the aura it projects is more deadly."